# Incomplete Understanding of the Application of Suprema Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

In studying a book on probability, I read the following:

For a sequence bounded from above there exist all of the suprema

$$v_n = sup [x_n, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},...]$$

with $v_1 >= v_2 >=  v_3 ...$

I assume this is interpreted as follows:

$$v_1 = sup [x_1, x_2, x_3, ...]$$
$$v_2 = sup [x_2, x_3, x_4, ...]$$
$$v_3 = sup [x_3, x_4, x_5, ...]$$

Therefore it seems $v_1=v_2=v_3$.

I don't see how the following could ever be true:
$$v_1 > v_2 > v_3$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, for instance, $x_n=\frac1n$, then\begin{align}v_1&=\sup\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\right\}=1\\v_2&=\sup\left\{\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots\right\}=\frac12\\v_3&=\sup\left\{\frac13,\frac14,\frac15,\ldots\right\}=\frac13\end{align}and so on. And indeed $v_1>v_2>v_3>\cdots$